Show that $\mu((\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_k)^c)=0$.
Let $(X, \mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $X_i$ be a increasing sequence of subsets of $X$, that is $X_1\subset X_2\subset\dots \subset \cup_{n=1}^\infty X_n=:X$ with $\mu(X_n)<\infty$ for all $n$. Let $F_k\subset X_k$ for all $k=1,2,3,\dots$ so that $\mu(F_j)<2^{-j}$. Define $E_k:=X_k\setminus F_k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Show that $\mu((\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_k)^c)=0$.
Question:
(1) How do we get $$(\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_k)^c=\cap_{k=1}^\infty (X_k^c\cup F_k)\subset \cup_{n=1}^\infty\cap_{j=n}^\infty F_j$$
(2) can we use another approach to get the result? I am not sure if this is correct:
$$
(\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_k)^c=\cup_{j=1}^\infty X_j\setminus(\cup_{k=1}^\infty X_k\setminus F_k)=\cup_{k=1}^\infty(X_k\setminus (X_k\setminus F_k))?
$$

@SassatelliGiulio But this is not straightford for me. Is there another way to show that result $(\cup E_k)^c$ is a null set?
